# Internal Hard Drive SATA Connector "Fins" Causing Misalignment?

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I'm re-purposing an internal hard drive to an external one. The only problem is that my SATA connector that is supposed to go onto the SATA pins doesn't fit due to having some kind of connector fins which are blocked by the hard drive mounting bracket. How can I connect these two?

[image: Fins]
[image: Attempted Connection]
[image: Pins]

Comment: I looks like there is an adapter on the hard drive, pull it off of the drive.

Comment: @Moab Confirmed, it's probably due to my relative inexperience with hardware. I didn't even notice that it was an adaptor. It slid right off. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it and upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looks like there is an adapter on the hard drive, pull it off of the drive, now you will have the regular sata connections.